# SQL query using joins for one to many table having a where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am looking for query using joins to find, list of departments which have all employees having age less than 30, In the below example the result i am looking for is '*Computers*' as all the employees are having less then 30 age

`Department` table:

```
Id  | Department Name 
100 | Computers
101 | Electronics
102 | Mechanical
```

`Employee` table

```
Id  | DepartmentId | Employee Name | Age
901 | 100          | Sam           | 25
902 | 100          | Ram           | 28
903 | 101          | Joe           | 35
904 | 101          | Kate          | 27
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select departmentid
from employee e
   inner join department d on d.Id = e.departmentId
group by e.departmentid —- all columns from Department which are needed
having max(e.age) < 30
```

Comment: This worked for me, gave only department 'Computers' which is what i am looking for

Comment: @nagendra this query does an unnecessary join. If you only need the id of the department (this is what this query does) then there is no need to join the table department.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select d.id, d.department_name
from department d
where not exists (
    select 1
    from employee e
    where e.department_id = d.id and e.age >= 30
)
```

The same logic can be phrased with a `left join` antipattern:

```
select d.id, d.department_name
from department d
left join employee e on e.department_id = d.id and e.age >= 30
where e.id is null
```

Comment: I can’t agree with second way. It will return duplicates for each employee who is younger 30

Comment: @BasilKosovan: well, no it won't. Please have a look at [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9527741c9dd94334afc4d764eb43052) for your reference.

Comment: with the second query its returning  'Mechanical' as well which has no employees

Answer (score 2):

With this query:

```
select departmentid
from employee
group by departmentid
having max(age) < 30
```

you get all the `departmentid`s with employees aged < 30.
So use it like this:

```
select * from departments
where id in (
  select departmentid
  from employee
  group by departmentid
  having max(age) < 30
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `join` is not the most natural way to write such a query.  `not exists` is:

```
select d.*
from departments d
where not exists (select 1
                  from employees e
                  where e.DepartmentId = d.id and e.age >= 30
                 );
```

A simple way to turn this into a `join` is:

```
select d.*
from departments d left join
     employees e
     on e.DepartmentId = d.id and e.age >= 30
where e.id is null;  -- no matches
```

Comment: @BasilKosovan . . . Please explain.